# '::this' syntax in react is giving error in vs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am getting error in VS Code Editor. It gives me syntax error when using `::this` in react 
My code is like this :

```
constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.followRecruiter = ::this.followRecruiter;
}

followRecruiter(rpId) {
      // write something here...
}
```

[image: See the picture]

Comment: Have you got the appropriate plugin installed? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-function-bind

Comment: Hi Evan
This is not the issue with code. My code is working fine but VS Code shows me red mark as mentioned in image which I don't like.